# Spring Data JPA One to Many relationship not saving child table

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

Parent Entity

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "paramRef", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set getParamList() { return this.paramList; }
```

Child Entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "param_Ref_Id", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
public ParamRef1 getParamRef() { return this.paramRef; }
```

Code to persist

```
ParamRef1 pr = new ParamRef1();
pr.setName("TEST PARAM");

Param1 p1 = new Param1() p1.setParamValue("ONE") p1.setParamRef(pr);
Param1 p2 = new Param1() p2.setParamValue("TWO") p2.setParamRef(pr);

Set paramList = new HashSet() paramList.add(p1) paramList.add(p2)

pr.setParamList(paramList)

pr = paramRefDao1.save(pr)
```

Please let me know if the steps are correct. I am getting following exception. and not able to understand why parent id is not available in child table

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PARAM_REF_ID', table
>   'PARAM'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing value for the column `PARAM_REF_ID` for the parent table

```
ParamRef1 pr = new ParamRef1();
pr.setName("TEST PARAM");
pr.setParamRefId(1); // replace 1 with any other valid id as value
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Actually I am using Identity in my ms sql server for my parent and child table. So my parent table doesnt have any issue in storing PK  field value. but at the same time, while persisting the child table, parent key id is not available. any guess what is missing or wrong in my code?